# Cannot output the expected when using arralist along with for looop

Tags: java

I am asked to output the index of smallest and largest rectangle from a group of valid rectangles that built up from user's type-in.

I did a filtering to store the valid rectangle to arraylist 'recB'. However, when I was finding out the largest and smallest rectangle from the valid rectangles, it seems never output both the smallest and largest correctly.

Rectangles are labelled by index input by users, from 1-4. I declare two 'int' named 'smallestIndex=0' and 'largestIndex=0' to whom the right index would be put and then output them. But it always print like "Smallest: Rectangle 0, Largest:xxx" or the other way around.

So I think one of "smallestIndex" or "largestIndex" may not be aligned the right index, but cannot figure it out.
I attach the codes from determining invalid ones and storing the valid ones as below:

```
//Determing and display the invalid rectangles
//and store the valid rectangles to arraylist 'recB' 
//Determining invalid ones
System.out.println("Invalid rectangles which are out of screen range: ");
for(int i=0; i<rec.length; i++){
  if(rec[i].getX()+rec[i].getWidth()>1000||(rec[i].getY()+rec[i].getHeight())>800){ 
    System.out.printf("Rectangle %d",rec[i].getIndex());
    rec[i].outputRectangle();
  }
//Storing the valid ones
  else{
    recB.add(rec[i]);
  }
}

//5.Determing and diplay index of the smallest and largest valid rectangle
//Create variable to store index of smallest and largest rectangle
int smallestIndex=0;
int largestIndex=0;
//Smallest rectangle

smallest = recB.get(0).getWidth()*recB.get(0).getHeight();
for(Rectangle rr:recB){
  if(rr.getWidth()-rr.getX()*rr.getHeight()<smallest){
    smallestIndex=rr.getIndex();
  }

}


//Largest rectangle
largest = recB.get(0).getWidth()*recB.get(0).getHeight();;
for(int i=0; i<recB.size(); i++){
  if(largest< recB.get(0).getWidth()*recB.get(0).getHeight()){
    largestIndex=recB.get(i).getIndex();
  }
}

//Output smallest and largest rectangle
System.out.printf("The Smallest: Rectangle %d\n",smallestIndex);
System.out.printf("The Largest: Rectangle %d\n",largestIndex);
```

}
}

---

Just remind that I put the Rectangle class, revised RecTester and a output below.

```
Rectangle class:
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Rectangle {
  //Create instance variables//
  private int index;
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private int width;
  private int height;

  //Create Scanner
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Declare default Constructor//
  public Rectangle(){

  }

  //Declare alternative Constructor//
  public Rectangle(int index, int x, int y, int width, int height){
    this.index=index;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;
  }

  //Declare methods//
  //1 Create setXY to set x,y for rectangle
  public void setXY(int x, int y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;    
  }
  //2 Create getX to get value of X from rectangle
  public int getX(){
    return this.x;
  }
  //3 Create getY to get value of Y from rectangle
  public int getY(){
    return this.y;
  }

  //4 Create setWidth to set Width for rectangle
  public void setWidth(int width){
    this.width=width;
  }

  //5 Create getWidth to get value of Width from rectangle
  public int getWidth(){
    return this.width;
  }

  //6 Create setWidth to set Width for rectangle
  public void setHeight(int height){
    this.height=height;
  }

  //7 Create getHeight to get value of Height from rectangle
  public int getHeight(){
    return this.height;
  }

  //8 Create inputRectangle() for user to input data from keyboard.
  public void inputRectangle(){
    //Input valid value of X
    System.out.print("Index: ");
    index=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("x: ");
    this.x=input.nextInt();
    if(x<1||x>1000){
      System.out.print("The valid x is 1-1000, please input again.");
      this.x=input.nextInt();
    }

    //Input valid value of Y
    System.out.print("y: ");
    this.y=input.nextInt();
    if(y<1||y>800){
      System.out.println("The valid y is 1-800, please input again.");
      this.y=input.nextInt();
    }

    //Input valid value of Width
    System.out.print("width: ");
    this.width=input.nextInt();
    if(width<1||width>1000){
      System.out.println("The valid width is 1-1000, please input again.");
      this.width=input.nextInt();
    }

    //Input valid value of Height
    System.out.println("height: ");
    this.height=input.nextInt();
    if(height<1||height>800){
      System.out.println("The valid Height is 1-800, please input again.");
      this.height=input.nextInt();
    }  
  }

   //9 Create outputRectangle() to print out the info. of Rectangle.

  public void outputRectangle(){
    System.out.printf("(x,y)= (%d,%d)\n",x,y);
    System.out.printf("width= %d\n", width);
    System.out.printf("height= %d\n", height); 
  }

  //10 Create getIndex
  public int getIndex(){
    return index;
  }
}
```

---

Revised RecTester:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecTester_v2 {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //1. Create an array storing 4 rectangle
    Rectangle[] rec = new Rectangle[4];
    //Create an ArrayList to store valid rectangle
    ArrayList<Rectangle> recB = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();




    //2. Ouput prompt and user inputs the rectangle from keyboard
    for(int i=0; i<rec.length; i++){
      rec[i]=new Rectangle();
      System.out.printf("Rectangle %d\n",i+1);
      rec[i].inputRectangle();
    }
    //3. Output the information of each Rectangle ande diplay index of invalid rectangle
    //Output the information of each Rectangle
    for(int i=0; i<rec.length; i++){
      System.out.printf(" Rectangle %d\n",i+1);
      rec[i].outputRectangle();
    }

    //Determing and display the invalid rectangles
    //and store the valid rectangles to arraylist 'recB' 
    System.out.println("Invalid rectangles which are out of screen range: ");
    for(int i=0; i<rec.length; i++){
      if(rec[i].getX()+rec[i].getWidth()>1000||(rec[i].getY()+rec[i].getHeight())>800){ 
        System.out.printf("Rectangle %d\n",rec[i].getIndex());
        rec[i].outputRectangle();
      }
      else{
        recB.add(rec[i]);
      }
    }

    System.out.println("Size of recB is: "+recB.size()); //Test recB's size

    System.out.println(" Content of recB(Valid Rectangles)");//Test content of recB
    for(Rectangle rB: recB){
      System.out.printf("Rectangle %d\n",rB.getIndex());
      rB.outputRectangle();
    }


    //4.Determing and display average area of valid rectangles
    //Create variable to compute average area
    double average=0;
    int sum=0;
    int count=0;
    for(Rectangle r: rec){
      if(r.getX()+r.getWidth()<1000&&(r.getY()+r.getHeight())<800){
      sum=sum+(r.getWidth())*(r.getHeight());      
      count++;
      }
    }
    average=(double)sum/count;
    System.out.println("sum is: "+sum);// To examine value of sum
    System.out.printf("The average area of qualified rectangle is %.2f\n",average);

    //5.Determing and diplay index of the smallest and largest valid rectangle
    //Create variable to store index of smallest and largest rectangle
    int smallest=0;
    int smallestIndex=0;
    int largest=0;
    int largestIndex=0;
    //Smallest rectangle

    smallest = recB.get(0).getWidth()*recB.get(0).getHeight();
//    for(Rectangle rr:recB){
//      if(rr.getWidth()*rr.getHeight()<smallest){
////        smallest=(rr.getWidth()-rr.getX())*(rr.getHeight()-rr.getY());
//        smallestIndex=rr.getIndex();
//      }    
//    }
// 
    for(int i=0;i<recB.size();i++){
      if(smallest> recB.get(i).getWidth()*recB.get(i).getHeight()){
        smallestIndex=recB.get(i).getIndex();
      }  
    }
    //Largest rectangle
    largest = recB.get(0).getWidth()*recB.get(0).getHeight();
    for(int i=0; i<recB.size(); i++){
      if(largest< recB.get(i).getWidth()*recB.get(i).getHeight()){
//        largest = (recB.get(0).getWidth()-recB.get(0).getX())*(recB.get(0).getHeight()-recB.get(0).getY())
        largestIndex=recB.get(i).getIndex();
      }
    }

    //Output smallest and largest rectangle
    System.out.printf("The Smallest: Rectangle %d\n",smallestIndex);
    System.out.printf("The Largest: Rectangle %d\n",largestIndex);  
  }

}
```

---

Input and output

```
 Rectangle 1
(x,y)= (1,1)
width= 5
height= 5

 Rectangle 2
(x,y)= (999,799)
width= 2
height= 2

 Rectangle 3
(x,y)= (1,1)
width= 20
height= 20

 Rectangle 4
(x,y)= (1,1)
width= 10
height= 10

Invalid rectangles which are out of screen range: 
Rectangle 2
(x,y)= (999,799)
width= 2
height= 2

Size of recB is: 3
 Content of recB
Rectangle 1(x,y)= (1,1)
width= 5
height= 5

Rectangle 3(x,y)= (1,1)
width= 20
height= 20

Rectangle 4(x,y)= (1,1)
width= 10
height= 10

sum is: 525
The average area of qualified rectangle is 175.00
The Smallest: Rectangle 0
The Largest: Rectangle 4
>
```

Comment: `get(0)` where `get(i)` should have been. Use spaces for easier reading.

Comment: @JoopEggen it is, but why is OP subtracting the width from the value of `getX()` and then multiplying by the height?  also, wouldn't it be easier to call a method to calculate the area of the rectangle

Comment: @JoopEggen, my mistake, the second for loop for the largest does need `.get(i)`

Comment: can you edit your post and share your Rectangle class? it seems like you are interchangeably using `getX()` and `getWidth()` and `getY()` and `getHeight()`

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post and you can see the output as well. I quit don't understand why 'Rectangle 0' popped up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would re-read your code and make sure you are using the same style for everything.  For example, you are using an enhanced for loop to calculate your smallest rectangle and a standard for loop to calculate your largest.

Secondly, I would try the following code

```
smallest = recB.get(0).getWidth() * recB.get(0).getHeight();
for (Rectangle rr : recB) {
  if (rr.getWidth() * rr.getHeight() < smallest) {
    smallestIndex = rr.getIndex();
  }
}

//Largest rectangle
largest = recB.get(0).getWidth() * recB.get(0).getHeight();
for (int i = 0; i < recB.size(); i++) {
  if (largest < recB.get(i).getWidth() * recB.get(i).getHeight()) {
    largestIndex = recB.get(i).getIndex();
   }
}

//Output smallest and largest rectangle
System.out.printf("The Smallest: Rectangle %d\n", smallestIndex);
System.out.printf("The Largest: Rectangle %d\n", largestIndex);
```

Comment: @JunlongWang if this solved your request please mark it as the solution, if not, reply in a comment with your new error

Comment: Hi , thank you for your instant reply! I have made them the same style and changed .get(0) to .get(i) in largest. However, the problem is not gone. I write other two line of codes to examine the size of 'recB' and print out the content inside 'recB', what shows up is exactly what I typed in and is complied with the rule(invalid/valid). But when it comes to find out largest and smallest, it still shows ' Rectangle 0' for either Smallest or Largest, and even sometimes the index of invalid rectangles. I really don't know what is going onCould you think about other possibility of this problem?

Comment: if you add a for loop that prints out the area of each rectangle in `recB`, what is the output?

Comment: I wanna show the revised codes and output to you, but I can't put so many words in this text area. How could I make it ? Cheers

Comment: if you are looking at the area of each rectangle, are they all the same or is there a `largest` and `smallest`?